# How can I lock my taskbar to my second monitor in Windows 11

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11, taskbar

In windows 10 I could put the taskbar on whichever monitor I wanted, but that capability seems to have been removed in Windows 11. I've been using a program called StartAllBack but while it does let me move the taskbar to a 2nd monitor, whenever the computer sleeps it reverts to the primary monitor. This is true whether I lock the task bar or not.

Please note that changing which monitor is my primary monitor isn't a helpful solution. Most videogames will start on the primary monitor and many do not have options to switch which monitor they display on. I need to have my taskbar on a different monitor from primary for this and other reasons.

Comment: How is the second monitor connected ? DisplayPort ?

Comment: There are two options for the taskbar, extend it across both monitors or display it on the primary monitor. Sounds like your current issue is caused by StartAllBack

Comment: @Ramhound In windows 10 you could put the task bar on any monitor. In W11 it can only be on the primary monitor. StartAllBack 1/2 fixes the problem - I'm looking for an actual full solution.

Comment: @harrymc All three monitors are DP yes.

Answer (score 1):

DisplayPort acts as a PNP device, so turning off the monitor,
even for an instant, is treated as if it was removed and
windows are moved out and rearranged because Windows forgets
this device, until it is turned on again and is "discovered".

The problem is with the StartAllBack program that doesn't recover
well from the situation where the designated monitor is
momentarily absent, so chooses some other monitor for the taskbar.

A solution which will prevent Windows from verifying the continued
presence of a DisplayPort monitor, so not detect that it's off,
is to keep the
[Extended Display Identification Data (EDID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data)
properties of the monitor.

A solution for NVIDIA cards is detailed in
[Managing a Display EDID on windows](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3569/%7E/managing-a-display-edid-on-windows)
by setting the monitor to use the EDID from file instead of
from the monitor, so auto-detect is in effect disactivated.

Another method uses the old and free utility for setting up the
EDID is the
[Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU),
which probably still works today.

If these methods do not solve the problem of StartAllBack,
you might need to restart StartAllBack or re-specify the monitor
for the taskbar. You could also search for an
[alternative product](https://alternativeto.net/software/startallback/)
(don't try ExplorerPatcher).

Comment: This sounds like it's at least the start of a solution. Also explains why it happens semi-randomly and also sometimes when I activate my KVM switch.